# Firebase in iOS9 Swift. CFNetwork SSLHandshake

Tags: firebase, ssl-certificate, ios9, cfnetwork, swift2

This is my first time integrating firebase. I am getting logs of 'CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807)' while connecting to firebase. My code is just one line :

`Firebase fireBase = Firebase(url: "https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/samplechat/messages/-JqpIO567aKezufthrn8/text")`

I know this question has been asked many times of which solution is to update plist but I have updated my info.plist also.

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <!--Connect to anything (this is probably BAD)-->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Is there anything I am missing on ?

Comment: What version of Firebase are you using?

Comment: 2.4.3 ... Same app is working for url "https://firechat-ios.firebaseio-demo.com/" but not for my own url or the one mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

The key 'NSAllowsArbitraryLoads' should be placed under 'Exception Domains'.

But the official reference says:
'Enabling this key can also be useful for debugging and development purposes.'

Then I tried and passed with the setting below:

- App Transport Security Settings

  - Exception Domains(dic)

    - firebase.com(dic)  *for libraries

      - NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy(bool) = NO
    - firebaseio.com(dic)  *for space

      - NSIncludesSubdomains(bool) = YES (=> *for accepting your space subdomain)
      - NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy(bool) = NO